# Sending emails in Celery tasks not executing

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a view function in Django, which receives a post request with the data of sending letters (the poster post, the topic of the letter, message, etc.) from the user and transmits them to Celery Tasks, to send letters through standard function of the Django send_mail. For some reason, Celery Task is not performed.
Using: Django, Redis, Celery, Docker

Project structure:

`sender`

```
- sender
  -- __init__.py
  -- asgi.py
  -- celery.py
  -- settings.py
  -- urls.py
  -- wsgi.py
- emails
  -- migrations
  -- __init__.py
  -- admin.py
  -- apps.py
  -- forms.py
  -- models.py
  -- tasks.py
  -- tests.py
  -- views.py
- templates
- venv
- db.sqlite3
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- manage.py
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .tasks import *
from .models import *
from .forms import *


def send_some_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            from_mail = form.cleaned_data['from_mail']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            cat = form.cleaned_data['cat']
            limit = form.cleaned_data['limit']

            try:
                send.delay(from_mail, subject, message, cat, limit)
                return redirect('home')

            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                return redirect('errorpage')

    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'emails/index.html', {'form': form})
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from .forms import *
from django.core.mail import send_mail


@shared_task
def send(from_mail, subject, message, cat, limit):

    for element in Emails.objects.filter(active=True, category__name=cat)[:limit]:
        send_mail(subject=subject,
                  from_email=from_mail,
                  message=message,
                  recipient_list=[str(element), ])
        print(str(element))
        element.active = False
        element.save()
    return True
```

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /apps

COPY requirements.txt /apps
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /apps

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
CMD ["2525"]
```

`docker-compose:`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always

  sender:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    command: ['celery', '-A', 'sender', 'worker', '-P', 'solo']
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

`celery.py:`

```
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sender.settings')

app = Celery('sender')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

`sender/sender/__init__.py:`

```
from .celery import app as celery_app`
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

`docker commands:`

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

Tried adding `-P`, `solo` when starting celery worker, because I run from windows but it did not help.

Comment: Could you share your email settings? (please make sure to hide your password)

Comment: EMAIL_HOST = 'connect.smtp.bz'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_host_user'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my_password"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'


CELERY_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379"